# How to go to next line after certain width ItextSharp c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext, pdf-generation

i'm working on small desktop level windows application,
i'm trying to build a resume using user's data and write into a pdf file.

in pdf i need to have new line after some width of text.

```
 BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD); //Font.normal for normal...

        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(new Chunk("ASHUTOSH ANIL KALE", font));
        p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        doc.Add(p1);

        BaseFont bf2 = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(new Chunk("F-6 chaiyana-sagar apartment,road no-7, gulmohar colony,south shivaji nagar, sangli mahrashra, India ", font2));
        p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

        doc.Add(p2);
```

for the above code i'm getting this output

[image]

But i need in this format,
what should to go next line after few width

[image]

Comment: How much is "some width" or "few width" of text?

Comment: after 80-100 characters

Comment: Then simply split the string at a space character *after 80-100 characters* (If the string is really long, split the remaining string again and again in a similar fashion) and add each partial string in a separate paragraph to the document.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to split that word by (",") and then add new line or new paragraph for remaining words

you can simply add new line like this

```
document.Add(new Chunk("\n"));
```

or you can try like this

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph(" "));

//just give a space between (" ") and it will work
```